# Rearrange numbers content within a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

i trying to shuffle the numbers currently contained within a listbox.

However getting an error with my index

I am able to do this with an array, although now I am trying to shuffle without the use of any containers or arrays, but having problems doing so.

```
this.index = 0;
int a = Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items.Count);
lstHoldValue.Items.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
    int idx = rnd.Next(i, a);

    //swap elements
    int tmp = Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[i]);

   (lstHoldValue.Items[i]) = Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[idx]);
    (lstHoldValue.Items[idx]) = Convert.ToInt32(tmp);
    lstHoldValue.Items.Add("\t" + Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[i]));//show array in a listbox                    

}
```

Comment: You get the amount of items in the list, then you clear the list. So this has the effect of making that amount you first got wrong 99% of the time.

Comment: thanks but its seems to repeat the numbers a second time, when i take out the clear

Comment: Thats because of the add to list line... really you need to make a copy of the list to work with and then modify that copy as desired then make the list use that

Comment: have no idea how to do that

Comment: You cleared The Items,what are you tying to accomplish?

Comment: yeah I removed the clear line, and it'll shuffle the numbers, but then outputs them twice onto listbox. As Sayse suggested i need to copy the list and modify the copy version

Answer (score 0):

`this.index = 0;`//what is this for?

`int a = listHoldValue.Count;`//Count returns an integer by default

// lstHoldValue.Items.Clear();  //remove this line,it clears the items stored

```
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
    int idx = rnd.Next(i, a);

//swap elements


 int tmp = Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[i]);
        lstHoldVAlue.Items.Insert(i,lstHoldValue.Items[idx]);
   (lstHoldValue.Items[i]) = Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[idx]);
    (lstHoldValue.Items.Insert(idx,temp);
lstHoldValue.Items.Add("\t" + Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[i]));//this line is redundant because you have already added item[i] at index [idx]
```

}